# Using SwipeRefreshLayout with Viewpager and Tablayout

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout, swiperefreshlayout

I have 3 tabs and these tabs have recyclerview within swiperefreshlayout. I cannot change these tabs with swipe. I think this is because, my touch event is getting received by swiperefreshlayout instead of tablayout. How to solve my problem?

**Following is my layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/news_swipe_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.nabinkhadka.hamrodang.activity.NewsActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/news_recycler_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/viewpager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Problems:

> 1. If I move ViewPager above RecyclerView, then the swipe works but Recyclerview cannot be seen.
> 2. If I create a Relativelayout for these two and place each one above the other, I won't be able to make touch events on one of them

How can I get a work around?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You should change your layout design. Here is the solution:

1. Design a layout with `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` for your `Activity`.
2. Design another layout with `SwipeRefrashLayout` and `RecyclerView` for each TAB `Fragment`.
3. Finally, use `FragmentPagerAdapter` to populate Fragment's on `ViewPager`.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs_my_offers"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/view_pager_my_offers"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**fragment_tab.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**TabsPagerAdapter.java**

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
    super(manager);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return mFragmentList.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mFragmentList.size();
}

public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
    mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
}
}
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import company.screenshot.fundle.R;
import company.screenshot.fundle.points.adapter.TabsPagerAdapter;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

// TAG
private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

Context mContext;

ViewPager mViewPager;
TabLayout mTabLayout;

TabsPagerAdapter mTabsPagerAdapter;

// ToolBar
Toolbar mToolBar;

// Actionbar
ActionBar mActionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Context
    mContext = this;

    // ToolBar
    mToolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    if(mToolBar != null)
    {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolBar);

        mActionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        mActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        mActionBar.setTitle("History");
    }

    // Status bar :: Transparent
    Window window = this.getWindow();

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    {
        window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
        window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
        window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));
    }

    // Tabs
    mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs_my_offers);
    mViewPager  = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_my_offers);

    mTabsPagerAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    mTabsPagerAdapter.addFrag(new FragmentEarnedHistories(), "EARNED");
    mTabsPagerAdapter.addFrag(new FragmentRedeemedHistories(), "REDEEMED");


    mViewPager.setAdapter(mTabsPagerAdapter);
    mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);
    mTabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```